# How do i update the data(database) dynamically in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How do i update the database via options value in HTML ? i made it manually, in the examples below but i want it to update dinamically so i think i need to change something here but i don t know how.(example below) . database table name = 'proiecte', status_proiect = project status, contract semnat = contract signed.

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DL56W.png)
[img2 here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmSzf.png)

ShowController.php

```
public function update(Request $request, Proiecte $proiecte)
    {
        $proiecte->update($request->all());
        Proiecte::find($request->id)->update(['Status_Proiect' => 'Contract semnat']); <- **HERE I WANT TO MAKE IT DINAMICALLY**
        Proiecte::find($request->id)->save();
        // dd(Proiecte::find($request->id));
        return back();
    }
```

my home.blade.php

```
@foreach($data as $data)
                <tr class="table-row-data">
                    <td>{{ $data->id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $data->Denumire_Proiect }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $data->Firma_Client }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $data->Reprezentant_Firma }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $data->Contact_Client }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $data->Suma_Proiect }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $data->Numar_Transe }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $data->Status_Proiect }}</td>
                    <td>
                        {{-- <form action='home' method="POST"> --}}
                        <form action="{{ route('update') }}" method="POST">
                            @csrf
                            @method('put')
                            <select name="id">
                                <option value="{{ $data->id }}" name="pil">Proiect in lucru</option>
                                <option value="{{ $data->id }}" name="cs">Contract semnat</option>
                                <option value="{{ $data->id }}" name="pf">Proiect finalizat</option>
                            </select>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Schimbare</button>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
```

and now is the interesting part because i don t know how to update dinamically using  because i don t know how to get the information from the site when i select an option and i don t know how to write in the controller update function.

web.php

```
Route::put('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\ShowController::class, 'update'])->name('update');
```

i made it to work but not dinamically, but manually. if i enter any value where i said "HERE I WANT TO MAKE IT DINAMICALLY" it works, it updates my database when i press the btn "schimbare" (change btn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update the field, you need an input (select in thins case) and another input to keep the id

```
@foreach($data as $data)
    <tr class="table-row-data">
        <td>{{ $data->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data->Denumire_Proiect }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data->Firma_Client }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data->Reprezentant_Firma }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data->Contact_Client }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data->Suma_Proiect }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data->Numar_Transe }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data->Status_Proiect }}</td>
        <td>
            <form action="{{ route('update') }}" method="POST">
                @csrf
                @method('put')
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $data->id }}"/>
                <select name="Status_Proiect">
                    <option value="Proiect in lucru" {{$data->Status_Proiect == 'Proiect in lucru' ? 'selected':''}}>Proiect in lucru</option>
                    <option value="Contract semnat" {{$data->Status_Proiect == 'Contract semnat' ? 'selected':''}}>Contract semnat</option>
                    <option value="Proiect finalizat" {{$data->Status_Proiect == 'Proiect finalizat' ? 'selected':''}}>Proiect finalizat</option>
                </select>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Schimbare</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Then in your controller you use the two inputs `id` and `Status_Proiect` to update your entry

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    
    $projecte = Proiecte::findOrFail($request->id);
    $projecte->Status_Proiect = $request->Status_Proiect;
    $projecte->save();
    // dd(Proiecte::find($request->id));
    return back();
}
```

**2nd option using model binding**

If you want to use Model binding, you need to change the route, form action and your update method

```
Route::put('/home/{projecte}', [App\Http\Controllers\ShowController::class, 'update'])->name('update');
```

Form (you dont need the hidden input for the id anymore)

```
<form action="{{ route('update', ['projecte' => $data->id]) }}" method="POST">
                @csrf
                @method('put')
                <select name="Status_Proiect">
                    <option value="Proiect in lucru" {{$data->Status_Proiect == 'Proiect in lucru' ? 'selected':''}}>Proiect in lucru</option>
                    <option value="Contract semnat" {{$data->Status_Proiect == 'Contract semnat' ? 'selected':''}}>Contract semnat</option>
                    <option value="Proiect finalizat" {{$data->Status_Proiect == 'Proiect finalizat' ? 'selected':''}}>Proiect finalizat</option>
                </select>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Schimbare</button>
            </form>
```

Update method (you dont need to get the $projecte with find anymore)

```
public function update(Request $request, Proiecte $proiecte)
{
    $projecte->Status_Proiect = $request->Status_Proiect;
    $projecte->save();
    // dd(Proiecte::find($request->id));
    return back();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

below code update all request parameters.
`$proiecte->update($request->all());`

when you submit a form a array of field name as key and value as value will be send to server. the `$request->all()` contains this array.

```
<form action="{{ route('update') }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method('put')
        <select name="status">
          <option value="pil">Proiect in lucru</option>
          <option value="cs" >Contract semnat</option>
          <option value="pf" >Proiect finalizat</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Schimbare</button>
</form>
```

`<option>` tag not need `name` attribute . you must a name attribute to select tag and option tags have value attribute as value of select name

the `$request->all()` looks like this:

```
[
"status"=>"pil"
]
```

then you can update parameter

```
$proiecte->update([
'status'=>$request->input('status')
]);
```

Comment: hmm it doesnt work

Comment: "It doesn't work" will not help you. What you can better say is: "I tried your solution and I get the following error: (details). I've found the laravel.log and the error in the log is (details)

Comment: i tried your solution and i get no error, page still refreshing and i tried to $request->input('id') and if i select any option from <option> i get the id from the 2 existing records from my database(id 1 and id 2, and i get 1 for first row and 2 for second and i don t want that.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are passing the value of `$data->id` to each option incorrectly:

```
                <select name="id">
                    <option value="{{ $data->id }}" name="pil">Proiect in lucru</option>
                    <option value="{{ $data->id }}" name="cs">Contract semnat</option>
                    <option value="{{ $data->id }}" name="pf">Proiect finalizat</option>
                </select>
```

The database doesn't know which of the options (pil, cs, pf) to select based on this.

The value should be something unique for each option, you can either do it by ID's, or by string

```
           //Example 1
           <select name="id">
                <option value="0">Proiect in lucru</option>
                <option value="1">Contract semnat</option>
                <option value="2">Proiect finalizat</option>
            </select>

            //Example 2
            <select name="id">
                <option value="pil">Proiect in lucru</option>
                <option value="cs">Contract semnat</option>
                <option value="pf">Proiect finalizat</option>
            </select>
```

You already defined that the select statement name will be "id" here `<select name="id">` so the request passed is passing the value for `request()->id` based on it, you can also always do

`dd(request()->all())` to check what is actually being passed to your controller

For updating the request, you can do:

```
$proiecte->update(['Status_Proiect' => request()->id]);
```

Probably you should change the way the names of things are to not be confusing.

Comment: i tried your solution and i get error : 
Call to a member function update() on null

Comment: Change "Proiecte::find($request->id)->update(['Status_Proiect' => 'Contract semnat']);" to "$proiecte->update(['Status_Proiect' => request()->id]);"

Comment: @KGG there is no dynamic variable for the model binding in the route declaration. so $projecte is null. plus the id should be sent in a separate input.